# How can I wait for promises in a Socket.IO context

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, promise

I have this setup

```
//Client Side


 socket.emit('some_event');


//Server Side


 socket.on('some_event', function(data){
      socket.emit('another_event', getDataFromAPI());
 });
```

The thing is that my function `getDataFromAPI()` is a call that could take some time since it calls an external API and it uses promises. Something like that :

```
function getDataFromAPI(){
   myAPI.getStuffFromId('123456789')
   .then(function(data){
         return data;
   });
 }
```

If I use it this way, there will be nothing in the `getDataFromAPI()` in the socket.IO call scope which sends `null` to the client and prints `undefined` if I decide to print it. If I log it into the console inside the promise then I have data but it's a bit too late to return it.

Since I will be using promises call with that API a lot and most of my client / server real time communication will be made through Socket.IO is there something obvious that I am missing or is this simply a pattern I should not be using.

Comment: @JaromandaX would skip using them but I am kind of bound to the API wrapper which uses them :(

Answer (score 5):

Return the promise from your `getDataFromAPI` method.

```
function getDataFromAPI(){
   return myAPI.getStuffFromId('123456789')
     .then(function(data){
         return data;
     });
}
```

And emit when the promise is resolved.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.on('some_event', function(data){
      getDataFromAPI().then(function(apiData){
          socket.emit('another_event', apiData);
      })
   });
});
```

Comment: Ok I just realised I have some reading to do... thanks a lot works like a charm.

Comment: @phadaphunk You'll get the hang of it :)